# what does the "# Live" in the training window mean?

Tags: bixby

What does "5 Live" in the IDE training window mean?  This is not generated by the capsule, it is generated by the IDE.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  # of http request and type (live v. cached).
[image]